# qTip2 and Knockout.js enabled binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, qtip2

I am using qTip2 to display validation errors on input fields.
Under several conditions, set of input fields is hidden with knockout.js 'visible' binding, but qTip2 tooltips attached to those input fields remain visible.

Is there a way to extend 'visible' binding handler so that when elements are about to disappear, all related tooltips are also hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` in Knockout 3.x or `ko.applyBindingsToNode` in Knockout 2.x to apply other bindings to an element from within a custom binding.

So you can create a custom binding where in the `init` method you set up the 'visible' binding on that element that uses the observable passed into the binding. In the `update` method you can then call `hide` on the tooltip when that observable changes to `false`.

**JavaScript**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.qTip = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).qtip({
            content: 'Foo bar',
            hide: false,
            show: 'click',
            position: {
                my: 'left bottom',
                at: 'right centre'
            }
        });
        ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, {visible: valueAccessor()});
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var visible = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(!visible) {
            $(element).qtip('hide');
        }
    }
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.elementVisible = ko.observable(true);
    self.toggleVisibility = function () {
       self.elementVisible(!self.elementVisible());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="qTip: elementVisible">Click to show tooltip!!</div>
<button data-bind="click: toggleVisibility">Toggle visibility</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pa5pU/1/)

or if you would prefer that the custom binding only takes care of visibility and not the setup of the qTip itself: [another JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mh7sf/1/)

Comment: Thank you, not exactly what I was looking for, but example with applyBindingAccessorsToNode is good enough.